# Link without underline and using css

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway to don't underline link in html? I can't use style and css.

for example this code use "style" which can't be used in html emails, any other ideas? Css also can't be use. Thanks for help! It that even possible to achieve it without css/style?

```
<a href="http://empty.com" style="text-decoration: none;"><font color="f8931c"><i>Text...</i></font></a><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

As much as we want to avoid the dreaded important tag, for html email templates, you will have to add it to your `text-decoration` property like this:

```
<a href="http://empty.com" style="text-decoration: none !important;"><font color="f8931c"><i>Text...</i></font></a>
```

OR you can just wrap the text wihtin the anchor in a span and style the span instead like this:

```
<a href="http://empty.com"><span style="text-decoration: none !important;"><font color="f8931c"><i>Text...</i></font></span></a>
```

Comment: According to https://litmus.com/community/code/47-underlines-appearing-in-gmail-and-on-mac-apple-mail-6-web-based-and-mobile-devices it should.

Comment: The second way is from a comment there though @Icet so I'm not too sure about the span method.